# Populating data into sub-sheets from Master sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have a script that loops through a Master sheet looking for an "X" in certain columns to populate information into different "sub-sheets." The script is tied to a command button.

The script is working great but I'm trying to figure out how to first check to see if the record already exists in the sub-sheet before inputting the value. If the record exists, I want the script to skip adding the record.

Furthermore, I need the script to check to see if an X has been removed from the master sheet, which should remove the record from the sub-sheet.

As it is now, it's adding the same records every time the button is clicked, and if an X is removed from the master column, the record remains in the sub-sheet.

Here is what I have so far:

```
Sub PopulateAgents()

Dim c As Range
With Sheets("MASTER")

    For Each c In .Range("AB2:AB" & .Cells(Rows.CountLarge, "AB").End(xlUp).Row)
        If c.Value = "X" Then

            .Range("A" & c.Row & ":F" & c.Row).Copy Sheets("MA").Range("A" & _
                Sheets("MA").Cells(Rows.CountLarge, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1)
        End If

        Sheets("MA").Columns.AutoFit
    Next c

    For Each c In .Range("AM2:AM" & .Cells(Rows.CountLarge, "AM").End(xlUp).Row)
        If c.Value = "X" Then

            .Range("A" & c.Row & ":F" & c.Row).Copy Sheets("NY").Range("A" & _
                Sheets("NY").Cells(Rows.CountLarge, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1)
        End If

        Sheets("NY").Columns.AutoFit
    Next c
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: The obvious question which you haven't addressed is how to check for duplicates - what gives the game away?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
Sub PopulateAgents()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wsMaster As Worksheet
    Dim rMasterData As Range
    Dim aTransferParams() As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim lMaxCol As Long

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wsMaster = wb.Sheets("Master")

    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    '                                                                                                                         '
    '                                            Adjust these parameters as necessary                                         '
    '                                                                                                                         '
    'Change the first "1 to 2" to be "1 to n" where n is the number of sheets you'll be transferring to                       '
    'Leave the second "1 to 2" as is, no need to ever change that                                                             '
     ReDim aTransferParams(1 To 2, 1 To 2)
    '                                                                                                                         '
    'Set to the sheet you'll be transferring to:    Assign the column to be searched for X's    Perform this for each sheet   '
    Set aTransferParams(1, 1) = wb.Sheets("MA"):    aTransferParams(1, 2) = "AB"
    Set aTransferParams(2, 1) = wb.Sheets("NY"):    aTransferParams(2, 2) = "AM"
    '                                                                                                                         '
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

    'Get maximum column
    For i = LBound(aTransferParams, 1) To UBound(aTransferParams, 1)
        If wsMaster.Columns(aTransferParams(i, 2)).Column > lMaxCol Then lMaxCol = wsMaster.Columns(aTransferParams(i, 2)).Column
    Next i

    'Use max column to set master data range
    Set rMasterData = wsMaster.Range(wsMaster.Cells(1, "A"), wsMaster.Cells(wsMaster.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).Resize(, lMaxCol)

    'Turn off calcluation, screenupdating, and events to increase code speed and prevent "screen flickering"
    With Application
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    'Loop through each transfer paramter
    For i = LBound(aTransferParams, 1) To UBound(aTransferParams, 1)
        'Clear entries in destination sheet
        aTransferParams(i, 1).Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Offset(1).ClearContents

        'Filter for "X" in the appropriate column
        rMasterData.AutoFilter wsMaster.Columns(aTransferParams(i, 2)).Column, "X"

        'Copy over relevant data
        rMasterData.Offset(1).Resize(, 6).Copy aTransferParams(i, 1).Range("A2")
        aTransferParams(i, 1).Columns.AutoFit

        'Remove the filter
        rMasterData.AutoFilter
    Next i

    'Turn calculation, screenupdating, and events back on
    With Application
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With

End Sub
```